# Imperative followed by "rather than"?

Tags: imperatives

> Have in mind what you want to take a picture of beforehand - shoot a
>   single shot rather than taking many random pictures.

I came across this sentence and I'm confused about the verb following "rather than", it's in the -ing form but is it possible to have it in the infinitive as well?

I looked it up in my grammar book and it says that when using "rather than", the words before and after it should match, so the format should be infinitive-rather than-infinitive.
But this is in the imperative. What is the rule for this?

Answer (score 10):

[*Rather than*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rather%20than) is used both as a conjunction for infinitives and as a preposition.

In this example, *rather than* is a preposition, with a gerund as its object:

> Shoot a single shot **rather than taking** many random pictures.

Here it's a conjunction linking the infinitives *to shoot* and *to take*:

> She wanted **to shoot** a single shot **rather than take** many random pictures.

You can use *rather than* as a conjunction anywhere you can use an infinitive, including the bare infinitive of the imperative mood. (The verb following *rather than* is always a bare infinitive.)

In other contexts, use *rather than* as a preposition with a gerund. Note that [some people object to *rather than* as a preposition](http://www.englishrules.com/writing/2005/rather-than-and-instead-of/), preferring *instead of* for the non-infinitive uses.

Comment: I wouldn't class _taking_ as a 'gerund' in _Shoot a single shot rather than taking many random pictures_ - it echoes (I think that term hasn't been allotted a precise grammatical sense yet) _shoot_ rather than _single shot_. It's too far towards the verb end of the noun - verb continuum to be labelled _gerund_. Thus, I'm also having difficulty accepting _rather than_ as a (compound) preposition here. In _Tonight I think I’d like to go to a movie rather than go dancing_ it is very difficult to claim prepositionality. And I believe _rather than_ is more a subordinator with the -ing form also.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In “go to a movie rather than go dancing,” _rather than_ is a conjunction linking two infinitives (_go_ and _go_), not a preposition. The preposition + gerund form would be “go to a movie rather than going dancing.” I'm not sure what your objection is to calling it a gerund: It's an _–ing_ verb serving grammatically as the object of a preposition, a noun. What else would you call it? (Also note that American Heritage calls it a gerund in the linked article at the end.)

Comment: Ah, but it's an -ing form serving semantically more like a verb. And the grammar would be inconsistent:  “go to a movie rather than leisure / lancers / book / ball-game”. Typical nouns do not work here (apart from in to-PPs with the _to_ elided: "go to a movie rather than (to) school).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth “I'd like to go to a movie rather than a ball game” is fine. The other examples are wrong because of semantics and parallelism, not grammar. They wouldn't work with the preposition _instead of_ either. To return to the earlier example: _Dancing_ is a gerund in “I'd like (to go to a movie rather than) dancing,” with or without the parenthesized phrase.

Comment: But you can't use the similar  “I'd like (to go to a movie rather than) cake.” To quote Swan: "When -ing forms are used as verbs, adjectives or adverbs, they are often called 'present participles.' (This is not a very suitable name, because these forms can refer to the past, present, or future.) When they are used more like nouns, they are often called 'gerunds.' In fact, **the distinction is not really as simple as this**, and some grammarians prefer to avoid the terms 'participle' and 'gerund.'"
(Michael Swan, Practical English Usage, 2nd ed. Oxford Univ. Press, 1995) (bolding mine)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There's nothing wrong with the grammar of “I'd like (to go to a movie rather than) cake”; it's just terrible style because it subverts parallelism. In contrast, “I'd like (to go to a movie rather than) dancing” sets up a parallel between two [non-finite verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-finite_verb), the infinitive _to go_ and the gerund _dancing._ I honestly don't see what's objectionable about it or what's odd about calling it a gerund. It's a non-finite verb in the role of a noun, which makes it a gerund.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8868/discussion-between-bradd-szonye-and-edwin-ashworth)

Answer (score 0):

You've checked a grammar book & it gave you the answer you're looking for:

> "**Shoot** a single shot rather than **take** many random pictures"

is normal, standard, formal written English, but people don't speak English the way they write it; rather, they write it the way they speak it.

Comment: That's only half the story though – _rather than_ can be a conjunction or a preposition.

Comment: @Bradd: It's standard practice to cite references for this sort of claim & to give examples of how the usage rules for one form differs from those for the other. Otherwise, it's just a personal opinion with no support. No one can read your mind, & some of us prefer parallel structures regardless of whether we're using conjunctions or prepositions. If you're not going to tell the other half of the story, at least provide a pointer to where it is told.

Comment: Sorry, I figured you already knew that [_rather than_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rather%20than) was also a preposition, with an example in the original question (which is why it uses a participle rather than an infinitive). I wasn't sure whether you were acknowledging the other version as acceptable, or qualifying that it's only acceptable in speech.

Comment: @Bradd: The dictionary entry shows parallel construction in its examples. _M-W's Dictionary of English Usage_ (pp 797-798) says that when the phrases on either side are parallel, _rather than_ is a conjunction. It also says that using a gerund after _rather than_ is common, standard English. The fact is, **both forms are used** & seem acceptable. The dispute seems to be based on etymology rather than on current usage. If usage dictates what we can write in formal English--that's what the _CGEL_ claims--then either form is acceptable. I accept both forms but use parallelism where possible.

Comment: @Bradd: I hadn't read your answer before responding to your comment. Sorry about that. You gave references. I apologize for being too quick on the trigger. My problem, not yours.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought your posted answer might imply that the gerund form wasn't acceptable. I also prefer parallelism when possible, although in this specific case I think the conjunction form is stilted, and I'm not sure why. (And I posted my comment while I was still composing my own answer – sorry for not including the reference in the comment too. I'm a slow writer.)

Comment: @BraddSzonye What sort of conjunction do you claim "rather than" to be: coordinating or subordinating? If subordinating, why must the verb in the subordinate clause have the same form as the main verb? We don't do that with "before", "after" etc. If coordinating, then how so, seeing as a)  the "rather than" clause may precede the main clause; b) the meaning of "rather than" does not call for coordination, unlike the meanings of coordinating conjunctions *and, or, but* and *yet*.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would disagree

Consider this sentence

"Rather than tell/telling the truth, the children tried to fix the mistake on their own."

The question comes down to "Does the sentence mean ...

a/ Because the children prefer to lie, they decided to try and fix their mistakes on their own."

or

b/ The children should have told the truth, but they decided to try and fix their mistakes on their own."

Probably - it's b

Linguists (and yes, I am one) may well appear to say that EITHER one is OK
but with "tell" - 'rather than' is a conjunction
with 'telling' - 'rather than' is a preposition

but that just smells bad
... another word 'dictating' what they syntactical function is?

More likely, there is a difference in meaning

as such ... though we absolutely DO (and can) use either (fair enough)

only one is likely to be technically (in a semantic sense) ... right

and here - that is "telling," not "tell."

Comment: This answer seems to be about an ambiguity in what "rather than" *means* [a) "preferring to" b) "as opposed to; instead of"] rather than how people use it syntactically.

Comment: "Disagree" with what?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/412492)