# "Behead" or "beheads"?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, conjugation

My question is about the use of the form "beheads" in the following sentence from Victor Davis Hanson's essay ["Are the Orcs Winning?"](http://pjmedia.com/victordavishanson/are-the-orcs-winning/?singlepage=true):

> In contrast, Hamas only drives Christians out of Gaza rather than beheads them.

The form "beheads" sounds wrong to me; I would have said "rather than behead them." Now, I don't doubt that Dr. Hanson wrote it correctly; I'm sure he knows much more about language and grammar than I do. My question is, is "behead" also acceptable here? If so, is it a matter of formal vs. colloquial, or British vs. American usage, or what? Also, what would have been a better heading for this question? Is the form without "-s" an infinitive, or a subjunctive, or what?

Comment: I must be *very* "linguistically liberal". I don't really have a problem with any of ***beheads, behead, beheading*** (though I'd probably use ***beheading*** myself). And being a Brit, I'm easy about whether Hamas should take a singular or plural verb form.

Comment: Related: [Imperative followed by “rather than”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114510/imperative-followed-by-rather-than)

Comment: You’re using a finite verb when you need a non-finite one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel structure between the two options requires *beheads*. Both verbs need third person, singular, present form.

> Which is true? 1) Hamas drives Christians out of Gaza; or 2) Hamas beheads them [Christians]?

Part of the problem is the distinction between the factual and counterfactual. Most negations do not use a simple present form, but use helping verbs instead

> He goes to school. She does not go to school.

The speaker is stating *Hamas drives ...* but also *Hamas does not behead ...*.Instead of using the *does not* construction, he uses the conjunction *rather than* to negate. As [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rather+than) indicates, *rather than can take either infinitive forms or parallel conjugated forms.

> 1. — used with the infinitive form of a verb to indicate negation as a contrary choice or wish: *chose to sing rather than play violin*
> 2. and not: *obscures rather than resolves the problem*

If you wanted to rephrase because it sounds a bit off, you could say

> Hamas only drives Christians out of Gaza but does not behead them.

Note that the verb form *does* in this alternative is the third person singular, present, parallel to *drives*.

Another alternative is

> Hamas only drives Christians out of Gaza rather than beheading them.

Comment: Acting as a preposition, *rather than* needs an object, which means it need some sort of substantive, usually a noun but also something that can work like one. If you are going to feed it a verb, then the only way for that to be a noun is for it take either an  infinitive or a gerund.  That’s why both versions of “She always texts her dates when she stands them up rather than tell/telling them in person” work for this: one is a bare infinitive, the other a gerund. You certainly don’t need a tensed verb.

Answer (score 1):

No, *behead* is not acceptable in that particular instance; it would be a singular rather than a plural. Whether 'Hamas' should be treated as a collection of individuals, who *do* something or as a group which *does* something is a fruitful source of argument; there are several questions already on this site. However, if you have already said that Hamas *drives people out*, the corresponding word is *beheads*.

The confusion may come from the many constructions possible in the context, and only slightly different. The subjunctive would be *It has been suggested that the group drive the people out [next Sunday]* as opposed to *It has been suggested that the group drives people out [but I haven't seen it myself]*.  Another possibility would be the gerund, *...rather than beheading them.* But as written it is a simple present, which means the ending depends on number.