# "Rather than defend myself" <--Why are we allowed to use an infinitive after this preposition?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

> Rather **than defend myself**, I took a deep breath and tried to see his point of view.

In the above sentence, *than* is a preposition. So I thought the verb *defend* should have a form of *-ing* like *than defending myself*.

Why is the verb *defend* in the plain form?

Comment: Great question. Welcome to EL&U :)

Comment: It may relate to [another question today](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410801/which-is-the-correct-tense-to-use-here) where a preposition is followed by a gerund or noun. This question has a preposition followed by a transitive verb and an object.

Comment: Yes, the explanation is that that is how native speakers talk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imperative followed by "rather than"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114510/imperative-followed-by-rather-than)

Answer (score 3):

I think "than" is being used as a subordinating conjunction - introducing an exception or contrast. So I am not sure your concern applies.

Comment: I know dictionaries aren't the best sources for grammar information, but [Merriam-Webster seems to support its use as a conjunction](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/than). Although perhaps the best known example of than+verb is "easier said than done" where it's used with a past participle.