# Which is the correct tense to use here?

Tags: tenses

"In the meanwhile, is there anything else I'm supposed to do besides **studying** for the test?"

OR

"In the meanwhile, is there anything else I'm supposed to do besides **study** for the test?"

Which tense form is correct and why? Could someone please explain.

Comment: (+1) Any question which causes experts to disagree _must_ be a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Besides,* as used here, is a preposition and **requires a noun** or noun phrase.

*Studying* is a gerund and functions as a noun. *Study* here is also a noun: you can test that by adding something like *more:* "besides more study for the test".

All of [Oxford's examples](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/besides) follow *besides* with a noun (sometimes abstract, sometimes concrete; always a noun or noun phrase).

The question "which tense is right" is the wrong question, I'm afraid. But the answer is that both are correct, because neither is a verb.

Comment: Because neither is a **tensed verb**. Both gerunds and infinitives are verbs; they just don't have tense markers.

Comment: @JohnLawler My point is that *study* here is not a verb at all: it's a noun. And that's why *studying* works: although its not a tensed verb (or even, it is an untensed verb), it functions as a noun.

Comment: _Study_ is an infinitive parallel with _do_, or at least can't be distinguished from a 1-word infinitive clause in this sentence. The clause is of course a noun phrase, like all complement clauses. For many peoples' grammars, that makes _study_ a noun; for others' not. Certainly if one added an object _study geometry_, one would have to invoke a clausal NP.

Comment: I disagree that *study* in this sentence is an infinitive. It's a noun, meaning the act of studying. Certainly, if it were to be made a verb by adding an object, that changes things.

Comment: @AndrewLeach is "in the" used in the starting redundant? Can it be "meanwhile, is there anything else I'm supposed to do besides studying for the test?"

Comment: I disagree that "study" can only be interpreted as a **noun** (though it is always a **noun phrase**). _"is there anything else I'm supposed to do besides **more study**?"_ is only correct because "to do more study" is correct ("more study" is being compared to "anything", both are nouns) But it would be equally valid to say: _"is there anything else I'm supposed to do besides **study more**?"_. This is correct because "I should study more" is correct. ("study more" is being compared to "do anything", both are verbs).

Comment: A minor clarification to my earlier comment: (1) you can interpret study as a noun, because "I am supposed to do more study" (2) but you can also interpret it as a verb because "I am supposed to study more".

Comment: Also consider "Am I supposed to do anything besides call my mother?" where "call" is clearly a verb and can't possibly be used as a noun.

Comment: @Flater Yes, *call* is a verb. I would hold that as ungrammatical. It sounds completely wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

Both are acceptable. "besides studying for the test" may be slightly more formal.

"studying for the test" is a gerund.

In "study for the test", the verb "study" is in infinitive form, in parallel with "do".  (But you would never say "besides to study for the test".)

Comment: Hmmm. The more I think about this, the less I like the "study" option.